# CSS Text Alignment with Menu

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to align some text to the right of my vertical menu. As I included the entire code for this page, below is a link to it:

[Website Code](https://jsfiddle.net/mnfgo32g/)

Here is an image of what I'm trying to achieve. I have tried

```
display: inline-block;
```

and

```
display: inline;
```

[image]

So just as a recap lol, I want the text 'Changelog Ver: 0.1' to appear to the right of the vertical menu on the left.

Thanks.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated. Not sure if it's part of your problem, but you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: What can I use instead?

Comment: CSS. `text-align:center;` for text, `margin:0 auto;` for block-level elements. `<center>` is not in the HTML5 spec because it is a *stylistic* tag rather than a semantic / layout tag. All *stylistic* stuff should be done with CSS instead.

Answer (score 2):

For `display:inline-block` to work the way you want it to work your `.menu` also needs to be `display:inline-block`. You may also want to add a `vertical-align:top` to `#changetitle` so it moves to the top.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options and some things to change :

1 - If you want to use `display: inline-block;` you need to remove the margin right on your `#menu ul` and add `display: inline-block` on the `#menu`.

2 - if you want to use floats, add `float: left;` on the `#menu`.

3 - You can also uses `display: table`.

Best thing to do, have a look at this http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/

Answer (score 0):

### Methods

You could use one of the following methods:

- `float:left;` on `.menu`
- `display:inline-block;` + `vertical-align:top;` on `.menu`
- `position:absolute;` on `#changetitle`

With the `float` and `vertical-align` methods, you'll need to remove the  `margin-right` on `.menu ul` (`float` will also work if you give the menu a width). With `position:absolute` you're goning to spend a whole lot of time getting the `left` and `top` values right :P

### Which is best?

Probably `inline-block`. It's the easiest to set up, and just works. Best of all, it's *dynamic*. If you want to add another menu item at a later date and have to make the `.menu` div bigger, you don't have to change the CSS, whereas `float` usually would require you to set a width on `.menu` and `position:absolute` *definitely* requires that (as it is telling the browser exactly at what pixel to put `#changetitle`. If you're going to have more columns continue this design throughout the rest of the page, you *may* want to consider using `column` or `display:table` (**never** an actual `<table>` :P)

Long story short, use `inline-block`.

Here's a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mnfgo32g/12/